# Not displaying a column header when there is no data in that column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have the following code:

```
%table.table-base.table-striped#provider-payments-for-claim
  %thead
    %tr
      %th= t('provider_payments.check_date')
      %th= t('provider_payments.denial')
  %tbody
    - @provider_payments.each do |provider_payment|
      %tr{:id=>"provider-payment-#{provider_payment.id}"}
       %td= provider_payment.check_number
        %td= provider_payment.denial_reason.nil? ? '': provider_payment.denial_reason
```

It is correctly displaying provider_payment.denial_reason only if it is not null. The problem is, it's always displaying the column header:

```
%th= t('provider_payments.denial')
```

is there some way that I can **not** display this when all instances of provider_payment.denial_reason are nil?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to check if any `provider_payment` has `denial_reason`

```
%table.table-base.table-striped#provider-payments-for-claim
  %thead
    %tr
      %th= t('provider_payments.check_date')
      - if @provider_payments.any?(&:denial_reason)
        %th= t('provider_payments.denial')
  %tbody
    - @provider_payments.each do |provider_payment|
      %tr{:id=>"provider-payment-#{provider_payment.id}"}
       %td= provider_payment.check_number
       %td= provider_payment.denial_reason.nil? ? '': provider_payment.denial_reason
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course. You just need to add a conditional the same way you did for the `td` for the header. Make the condition the same (`provider_payment.denial_reason.nil?`).

erb version:

```
<% if @provider_payment.denial_reason.present? %>
  <th>...
<% end %>
```

Comment: What exactly would it look like? Originally I was trying %th= -@provider_payment.denial_reason.nil? ? '': t('provider_payments.denial') , but that is not working.

Comment: simplest would be to add a condition before the th: `if @provider_payment.denial_reason.present?` Then the th. Then an `end`